# Appbar should show number of records using futurebuilder in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have just created a demo for better understanding future builder

scaffold body showing all users from api and appear should be shown with number of users

appear's title showing 0 when loaded but does not change...what to do to rebuild it

here is my code

```
class _withmodelState extends State<withmodel> {

  List<UserModel> userlist=[];

  Future<List<UserModel>> getdata() async {
    final resp =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'));

    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      print('i ma called');
      List<dynamic> dlist = json.decode(resp.body);
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

      userlist= dlist.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      return userlist;
    }
    return userlist;


  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Total users="+userlist.length.toString()),),
      body: MyBody(
        //MyBody returning FutureBuilder for showing userlist array;
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ChangeNotifier` like this, first create a class like this:

```
class WithmodelDecl with ChangeNotifier {
  ValueNotifier<int> totalUsers = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
}

WithmodelDecl withmodeldecl = new WithmodelDecl();
```

then use it like this:

```
return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
          child: ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
              valueListenable: withmodeldecl.totalUsers,
              builder: (context, value, _) {
                return AppBar(
                  title: Text("Total users=" + value.toString()),
                );
              }),
          preferredSize: AppBar().preferredSize),
      body: MyBody(
        //MyBody returning FutureBuilder for showing userlist array;
      ),
));
```

and finally change your `getdata` to this:

```
Future<List<UserModel>> getdata() async {
    final resp =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'));

    if (resp.statusCode == 200) {
      print('i ma called');
      List<dynamic> dlist = json.decode(resp.body);
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

      userlist= dlist.map((e) => UserModel.fromJson(e)).toList();
      withmodeldecl.totalUsers.value = userlist.length;
      return userlist;
    }
    return userlist;


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to rebuild the `Text` widget, that you are using to show the count, when the count is available, i.e., the `Future` completes.

You need to wrap that `Text` widget with `FutureBuilder` like this:

```
return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: FutureBuilder<List<UserModel>>(
        future: getdata(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            final List<UserModel> userlist = snapshot.data!;
            return Text("Total users= ${userlist.length}");
            // it's better to use String interpolation than "Total users=" + snapshot.data!.length.toString()
          } else {
            // return loading widget
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
    body: MyBody(
      //MyBody returning FutureBuilder for showing userlist array;
    ),
  ),
);
```

It is better to have the `Future` in a variable, and then use it like this, to avoid unwanted and repeated calling of it whenever the `build()` method is called:

```
late final Future<List<UserModel>> _userListFuture;
```

And initialize it in your `initState()`, like this:

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _userListFuture = Future<List<UserModel>>(getdata);
}
```

And use it with your `FutureBuilder` like this:

```
FutureBuilder<List<UserModel>>(
  future: _userListFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      // return your widget showing data
    } else {
      // return loading widget
    }
  },
)
```